# Error while passing jmeter simple configuration in build.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle, jmeter, build.gradle, gradlew, gradle-kotlin-dsl

While trying to pass simple configuration in build.gradle.ktl file for running jmeter gradle. plugin (https://github.com/jmeter-gradle-plugin/jmeter-gradle-plugin/wiki/Getting-Started)

I am trying to pass simple configuration and my build.gradle.kts file looks like below

```
jmeter {
jmTestFiles = [file("src/test/jmeter/test2.jmx")] //if jmx file is not 
in the default location
jmSystemPropertiesFiles= [file("src/test/jmeter/jmeter.properties")] 
//to add additional system properties
enableExtendedReports = true //produce Graphical and CSV reports
}
```

I am encountering following error

> Script compilation errors:
>
> Line 7:   jmTestFiles = [file("src/test/jmeter/test2.jmx")]
>                             ^ Type mismatch: inferred type is Array but (Mutable)List! was expected
>
> Line 7:   jmTestFiles = [file("src/test/jmeter/test2.jmx")]
>                             ^ Unsupported [Collection literals outside of annotations]
>
> Line 8:   jmSystemPropertiesFiles=
>   [file("src/test/jmeter/jmeter.properties")]
>                                        ^ Type mismatch: inferred type is Array but (Mutable)List! was expected
>
> Line 8:   jmSystemPropertiesFiles=
>   [file("src/test/jmeter/jmeter.properties")]
>                                        ^ Unsupported [Collection literals outside of annotations]
>
> 4 errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the syntax had to be adopted to kotlin format below

jmSystemPropertiesFiles = mutableListOf(file("src/test/jmeter/jmeter.properties"))